# Notify on leaving a multicast group

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast, udpclient

I set up a listener on a multicastgroup

```
udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastaddress, localIpAddress);
while(listeing)
    data = udpclient.receive(ref remoteep);
```

Afaik i don't get informed when an other member in the same multicastgroup leaves.
I see it in wireshark under the IGMP Protocol.

How can i be informed when a member leaves the multicastgroup on my c# listener?

Comment: Send your own custom `leave` message.

Comment: yea that would do it for one case, but what about someone plugs the cable or terminates the app.

Comment: you can never detect that with UDP since the protocol is connectionless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no API for it at the C level so no way of implementing one at a higher level.

Comment: Ok, and maybe an idea for a workaround? It would be nice if a receiver would get informed if someone has disconnected else i would do some some "ping linke" messages and wait for replies, but i find this solution not nice.

Comment: @Gobliins You could have a look at some of the Reliable Multicast protocols like TRAM, LRMS etc for some ideas. But the basic idea of multicast is that you don't know or care who the peers are.